# Insert with stored procedure into multiple tables with foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to insert a new user into the following database I have created using a stored procedure.

The procedure is the following:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_user, insert_address, insert_new_user
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_user(@name VARCHAR(20), @sex CHAR(1), @date_of_birth DATE, @account_type INT, @id_address INT) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @position_user INT
    INSERT INTO [user]([user_name],[User_Sex], [date_of_birth], [account_type], [id_address])
    VALUES(@name, @sex, @date_of_birth, @account_type, @id_address)
    SELECT @position_user = @@IDENTITY
    SELECT @id_address = IDENT_CURRENT('address')
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_address(@street VARCHAR(255), @number INT, @locality VARCHAR(255), @city VARCHAR(255), @country_code CHAR(2) ) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @position_address INT
    INSERT INTO [address]([street], [number], [locality], [city], [country_code])
        VALUES(@street, @number, @locality, @city, @country_code)
    SELECT @position_address = @@IDENTITY
END
go
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_new_user(@name VARCHAR(20), @sex CHAR(1), @date_of_birth DATE, @account_type INT, @street VARCHAR(255), @number INT, @locality VARCHAR(255), @city VARCHAR(255), @country_code CHAR(2) )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id_user INT
    SELECT @id_user = [user].[id_user]
    FROM [user]
    WHERE [user].[user_name] = @name
    IF (@id_user IS NULL) 
    BEGIN
        EXEC insert_user @name, @sex, @date_of_birth, @account_type, @id_user
    end
        EXEC insert_address @street, @number, @locality, @city, @country_code
    END
GO
```

Which gives me the error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure insert_user, Line 5
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id_address', table 'dance_partner.dbo.user'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

If I set the field 'id_address' to NULL the procedure is "working" but the field "id_address" in the [user] table is set to NULL which I don't understand as I'm trying to get the field 'id_address' to reference the last id of the [address] table with

```
SELECT @id_address = IDENT_CURRENT('address')
```

What am I missing?

```
USE [master]
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS [dance_partner];
GO

CREATE DATABASE [dance_partner];
GO

USE [dance_partner];
GO

CREATE TABLE [user](
    [id_user] INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [user_name] VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [User_Sex] CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    [date_of_birth] DATE NOT NULL,
    [account_type] INT NOT NULL,
    [id_address] INT NOT NULL,
);

GO

CREATE TABLE [address](
    [id_address] INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [street] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [number] INT NOT NULL,
    [locality] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [city] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [country_code] CHAR(2) NOT NULL
);

GO

CREATE TABLE [membership](
    [account_type] INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [membership_name] VARCHAR(45) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    [membership_price] DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL
);

GO

CREATE TABLE [style](
    [style_ref] INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [style_name] VARCHAR(45) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE TABLE [dance](
    [id_dance] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [dancer_1_id_user] INT,
    [dancer_2_id_user] INT,
    [dance_dtg] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [style_ref] INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (dancer_1_id_user) REFERENCES [user] (id_user),
    FOREIGN KEY (dancer_2_id_user) REFERENCES [user] (id_user),
    FOREIGN KEY (style_ref) REFERENCES [style] (style_ref)  
);

GO

CREATE TABLE [user_dance_style](
    [id_user] INT,
    [style_ref] INT NOT NULL
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES [user] (id_user),
    FOREIGN KEY (style_ref) REFERENCES [style] (style_ref)
)


ALTER TABLE [user]
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user_memebership FOREIGN KEY (account_type)
      REFERENCES membership (account_type),
      CONSTRAINT fk_user_address FOREIGN KEY (id_address)
      REFERENCES address (id_address);

-- disable all constraints
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"

INSERT INTO [membership] ([membership_name], [membership_price])
VALUES 
('free', '0'),
('regular', '15'),
('premium', '30')
GO

INSERT INTO [style]([style_name])
VALUES
('Salsa'),
('Bachata'),
('Kizomba')

GO

INSERT INTO [user] ([user_name], [User_Sex], [date_of_birth], [account_type], [id_address])
VALUES 
('sara', 'f', '1990-04-23', '1', '1'),
('elenor', 'f', '1989-02-18', '1', '2'),
('eva', 'f', '1987-01-04','1','3'),
('mike', 'm', '1985-05-02', '1', '4'),
('phil', 'm', '1985-03-01', '1', '5'),
('laurent', 'm', '1986-02-14', '2', '6'),
('nidia', 'f', '1985-01-16', '2', '7'),
('franz', 'm', '1990-03-17', '2', '8'),
('stephan', 'm', '1991-05-23', '2', '9'),
('sandra', 'f', '1993-03-25', '3', '10'),
('virginie', 'f', '1999-05-03', '3', '11'),
('claire', 'f', '1992-02-24', '3', '12'),
('laurence', 'f', '1991-04-26', '3', '13'),
('pierre', 'm', '1987-02-14', '3', '14'),
('thierry', 'm', '1989-01-04', '3', '15'),
('nancy', 'f', '1950-04-15', '1', '16'),
('cédric', 'm', '1980-02-02', '1', '17')

GO

INSERT INTO [address] ([street], [number], [locality], [city], [country_code])
VALUES
('av de l''exposition', '13', 'laeken', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('rue cans', '2', 'ixelles', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('rue goffart', '32', 'ixelles', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('ch de haecht', '17', 'schaerbeek', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('rue metsys', '108', 'schaerbeek', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('rue du pré', '223', 'jette', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('rue sergent sorenser', '65', 'ganshoren', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('rue d''aumale', '38', 'anderlecht', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('av de fré', '363', 'uccle', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('rue de lisbonne', '52', 'saint gilles', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('av neptune', '24', 'forest', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('av mozart', '76', 'forest', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('rue emile delva', '92', 'laeken', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('av de la chasse', '68', 'etterbeek', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('rue leopold 1', '42', 'laeken', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('av charle woeste', '68', 'jette', 'bruxelles', 'be'),
('ch de boondael', '12', 'ixelles', 'bruxelles', 'be')

GO

INSERT INTO [user_dance_style] ([id_user], [style_ref])
VALUES
(1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3),(2, 1),(2, 2),(2, 3),(3, 1),(3, 2),(4, 1),(4, 2),
(4, 3),(5, 2),(5, 3),(6, 1),(7, 3),(8, 3),(9, 1),(9, 2),(9, 3),(10, 1),
(10, 2),(10, 3),(11, 3),(12, 2),(13, 2),(14, 1),(15, 3),(16, 1)

GO

INSERT INTO [dance]([dancer_1_id_user], [dancer_2_id_user], [dance_dtg], [style_ref])
VALUES
(1, 2, convert(datetime, '2019-11-24 10:34:09 PM',20), 3),
(4, 2, convert(datetime, '2019-11-24 10:50:00 PM',20), 3),
(3, 5, convert(datetime, '2019-11-24 10:35:00 PM',20), 2),
(6, 1, convert(datetime, '2019-11-24 10:37:00 PM',20), 1),
(7, 2, convert(datetime, '2019-11-24 10:37:00 PM',20), 3),
(8, 1, convert(datetime, '2019-12-03 11:20:03 PM',20), 3),
(9, 3, convert(datetime, '2019-12-23 10:45:00 AM',20), 1),
(10, 12, convert(datetime, '2019-12-26 11:20:00 AM',20), 2),
(11, 4, convert(datetime, '2020-01-02 08:45:00 AM',20), 3),
(12, 5, convert(datetime, '2020-01-02 11:10:04 AM',20), 2),
(13, 12, convert(datetime, '2020-02-04 09:25:00 PM',20), 2),
(14, 10, convert(datetime, '2020-02-25 10:45:00 AM',20), 1),
(2, 14, convert(datetime, '2020-02-25 08:45:00 PM',20), 1),
(5, 10, convert(datetime, '2020-03-01 11:15:06 AM',20), 2),
(17, 2, convert(datetime, '2020-03-04 03:15:06 AM',20), 1)

GO
```

Comment: @DaleK Thank you, make sense :) I see where I have to put it in the declaration but not where I have to put it in the calling?

Comment: I understand the logic but it is not working as the procedure has now too many arguments.

Comment: You should probably not use `@@Identity` and you should probably not trust `ident_current()`. [Use the right tool to get identity values back after an insert](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/10/03/use-the-right-tool-to-get-identity-values-back-after-an-insert/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code which corrects the issues you face.

1. You are guessing what the new address record ID will be and are inserting it into the user table before it exists. This is very bad practice, not only could it fail at some point, but you aren't using a foreign key to enforce the relationship - meaning you could end up with bad data in your database over time.
2. The easiest way to get a single value back from a stored procedure is to use an `OUT` parameter.
3. Following the referential integrity rules, you need to insert the address record first, so that it exists (this would be enforced if you had a foreign key), prior to inserting the user.

Full code below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_user
(
    @name VARCHAR(20)
    , @sex CHAR(1)
    , @date_of_birth DATE
    , @account_type INT
    , @address_id INT
    , @user_id INT OUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [user]([user_name],[User_Sex], [date_of_birth], [account_type], [id_address])
    VALUES(@name, @sex, @date_of_birth, @account_type, @id_address);

    -- If we inserted a row, get the new ID
    if @@ROWCOUNT = 1 set @user_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    RETURN 0;
END
go

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_address
(
    @street VARCHAR(255)
    , @number INT
    , @locality VARCHAR(255)
    , @city VARCHAR(255)
    , @country_code CHAR(2)
    , @address_id INT OUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [address]([street], [number], [locality], [city], [country_code])
    VALUES(@street, @number, @locality, @city, @country_code);

    -- If we inserted a row, get the new ID
    if @@ROWCOUNT = 1 set @address_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    RETURN 0;
END
go

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_new_user
(
    @name VARCHAR(20)
    , @sex CHAR(1)
    , @date_of_birth DATE
    , @account_type INT
    , @street VARCHAR(255)
    , @number INT
    , @locality VARCHAR(255)
    , @city VARCHAR(255)
    , @country_code CHAR(2)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @address_id INT, @user_id INT;

    EXEC insert_address @street, @number, @locality, @city, @country_code, @address_id OUT;

    IF @address_id IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        EXEC insert_user @name, @sex, @date_of_birth, @account_type, @address_id, @user_id OUT;
        -- Not sure what this does as @style is not defined anywhere
        -- But if it needs a user_id - we have one 
        -- EXEC insert_style @style;
    END;

    RETURN 0;
END
GO

EXEC insert_new_user 'tatiana', 'f', '1970-02-07', 1, 'rue steyls', 13, 'laeken', 'bruxelles', 'be';
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic here is a bit weird.

The `SELECT @id_address = IDENT_CURRENT('address')` statement is done after the insert statement. So how do you want the `@id_address` to be filled when inserting into `User` ?

With your model, you need to have an address to create user. So you must first create the address then create the user.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_new_user(@name VARCHAR(20), @sex CHAR(1), @date_of_birth DATE, @account_type INT, @street VARCHAR(255), @number INT, @locality VARCHAR(255), @city VARCHAR(255), @country_code CHAR(2) )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id_user INT,
            @new_id_address INT
    -- First step : create address and retrieve the generated address id
    -- NB : it means that you will always create an address but not always a user. So you will have some "zombie" addresses in your table. 
    -- -> Maybe this statement should be moved into the IF block to create address only if a user has to be created
    EXEC insert_address @street, @number, @locality, @city, @country_code, @new_id_address = @id_address OUTPUT
    -- 2nd step : optionally create a user.
    SELECT @id_user = [user].[id_user]
    FROM [user]
    WHERE [user].[user_name] = @name
    IF (@id_user IS NULL) 
    BEGIN
        -- Use the above selected id_address as an input parameter to create the user
        EXEC insert_user @name, @sex, @date_of_birth, @account_type, @id_address
    END
END
GO
```

To be able to achieve this you must alter your `insert_address` to get the newly generated @id_address

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_address(@street VARCHAR(255), @number INT, @locality VARCHAR(255), @city VARCHAR(255), @country_code CHAR(2), @id_address INT OUTPUT ) AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [address]([street], [number], [locality], [city], [country_code])
        VALUES(@street, @number, @locality, @city, @country_code)
    -- Outputs the generated address id
    SELECT @id_address = @@IDENTITY
END
GO
```

Finally you don't need to select an address id in user creation procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_user(@name VARCHAR(20), @sex CHAR(1), @date_of_birth DATE, @account_type INT, @id_address INT) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @position_user INT
    INSERT INTO [user]([user_name],[User_Sex], [date_of_birth], [account_type], [id_address])
    VALUES(@name, @sex, @date_of_birth, @account_type, @id_address)
    -- This statement is useless unless you define @position_user as an OUTPUT parameter
    SELECT @position_user = @@IDENTITY
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all trying to help.

I finally found something that achieves the desired result: creating a user and its corresponding address.

Even though it's working, I'm expecting it to not be correct in some way, I tried with all the solutions proposed on this thread but couldn't get them to work.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_user, insert_address, insert_new_user
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_user(@name VARCHAR(20), @sex CHAR(1), @date_of_birth DATE, @account_type INT) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id_address int
    SELECT @id_address = IDENT_CURRENT('address') + 1
    INSERT INTO [user]([user_name],[User_Sex], [date_of_birth], [account_type], [id_address])
    VALUES(@name, @sex, @date_of_birth, @account_type, @id_address)
END

go
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_address(@street VARCHAR(255), @number INT, @locality VARCHAR(255), @city VARCHAR(255), @country_code CHAR(2) ) AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [address]([street], [number], [locality], [city], [country_code])
        VALUES(@street, @number, @locality, @city, @country_code)
END
go
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_new_user(@name VARCHAR(20), @sex CHAR(1), @date_of_birth DATE, @account_type INT, @street VARCHAR(255), @number INT, @locality VARCHAR(255), @city VARCHAR(255), @country_code CHAR(2) )
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC insert_user @name, @sex, @date_of_birth, @account_type
    EXEC insert_address @street, @number, @locality, @city, @country_code
    EXEC insert_style @style
    END
GO


EXEC insert_new_user 'tatiana', 'f', '1970-02-07', 1, 'rue steyls', 13, 'laeken', 'bruxelles', 'be'
```

Comment: Your code has multiple remaining issues and will almost certainly break in the future. Please see my answer where I correct the issues.